# Jenkins Ant-Build Error

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins

I am new to Jenkins and I have little knowledge in its plugins configuration. One plugin I was using was Ant and I installed ant 1.8.2 then I want to add it to global system configuration manually but sadly I don't know what would I supply to it's ANT_HOME and because of that my project always fail see below. Any help would do much. Thanks.

[image: Jenkins Build Error]

Comment: are you working on dynamic or static slave ? , did you saw in the log the ANT installation ?

Comment: Sorry @MorLajb, I don't know what is static and dynamic slave but I was just working on master I run it through master. Thanks! And I kept getting this error, I just add ant manually which is same version with my machine. In my machine my script works well.

Comment: good for you , but Jenkins can install automatically the tools versions  for you. so I think you should understand why it didn't happen. try to in stall another ANT version in the Global tools to make sure you can do it. It will be easier for you in the future.

Comment: thanks @MorLajb I tried installing the ANT in global but still I can't get this one would you mind to check at my script if this is possible running in jenkins

I have batch file that will invoke a powershell script and powershell script will invoke the another batch and this batch contains this script

Comment: Sure , put your script / job I will have a look